# JsonObject Title not being applied in serialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a custom JSON object that I'd like to give a name to when it's serialized :

```
[JsonObject(Title = "AuthenticateResponse")]
public class AuthenticateResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the status message to return to the patron.
    /// </summary>
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Ils Message.
    /// </summary>
    public string IlsMessage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Ils code that was returned by the authentication attempt
    /// </summary>
    public string IlsCode { get; set; }
}
```

However, when this object is serialized, I'm only getting an output of the properties, without the object name :

```
AuthenticateResponse ar = new AuthenticateResponse();
ar.StatusMessage = "Test status Message";
ar.IlsMessage = "Test IlsMessage";
ar.IlsCode = "Code 614";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ar);
```

The output from `json` is :

```
{
     "StatusMessage": "Test status Message",
     "IlsMessage": "Test IlsMessage",
     "IlsCode": "Code 614"
}
```

What I would *like for it* to be is the following :

```
{
     "AuthenticateResponse": {
         "StatusMessage": "Test status Message",
         "IlsMessage": "Test IlsMessage",
         "IlsCode": "Code 614"
      }
}
```

**My Question :**

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class like JsonObjectContainer

```
public class JsonObjectContainer
{
    public JsonObjectContainer() 
    { 
         AuthenticateResponse=new AuthenticateResponse();
    }
    public AuthenticateResponse AuthenticateResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Use it instead of `AuthenticateResponse`

```
JsonObjectContainer ar = new JsonObjectContainer();
ar.AuthenticateResponse.StatusMessage = "Test status Message";
ar.AuthenticateResponse.IlsMessage = "Test IlsMessage";
ar.AuthenticateResponse.IlsCode = "Code 614";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ar);
```

Comment: While this does produce the right JSON output, I was more interested in using a specific JSON.Net attribute to accomplish this, without having to put wrap my objects in a container class. Is there no way to accomplish this without the wrapper?

Comment: I didn't find anything easier/cleaner

Comment: Understandable. While I do feel this could/should be improved upon, it does extract the right output, so technically you deserve the check. I just wish there was a more native JSON.Net way to accomplish this.

Comment: @X3074861X you could browse it's source and make it yours :D

Comment: @X3074861X Looking at this a few years later I realize the obvious, JSON cannot hold a key outside the root object and that's why you can't have a title for the root object.
when you hold that object inside another one it will have it's title property serialized in json